# Getting the intersection from two results

Tags: sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT utover.startnr, utover.navn, ovelse.navn
FROM utover, ovelse
WHERE ovelse.navn in (
SELECT DISTINCT ovelse.navn
FROM utover, deltakelse, ovelse
WHERE utover.navn = 'Carl Lewis'
AND deltakelse.utover = utover.startnr
AND deltakelse.ovelse = ovelse.navn
GROUP BY ovelse.navn, utover.startnr

INTERSECT

SELECT DISTINCT ovelse.navn
FROM utover, deltakelse, ovelse
WHERE utover.navn <> 'Carl Lewis'
AND deltakelse.ovelse = ovelse.navn
AND deltakelse.utover = utover.startnr
GROUP BY ovelse.navn, utover.startnr
);
```

Hey, I am trying to get out the name of (utover.navn) the person(s) that have had 'Carl Lewis' as an opponent. I am asking for the name and id from the intersection between the exercise(deltakelse.ovelse) where 'Carl Lewis' is in, and all the others. I should get one answer but I dont get anything. Anyone have some ideas?

Since I can't answere myself yet, I am just editing this. Here i get everyone that are 'Carl Lewis' opponent but not the "one" that only has has 'Carl lewis' as an opponent in his exercise. 
Hope it's ok that I did it like this

Comment: +1 for attempting to solve the problem. Please elaborate what do you expect as output.

Comment: I expect to get out one person's name 'Andreas Kvaale'. Found a way where i got everyone that had the same exercise's as the one I asked for, but not the only one that only had him as an opponent

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT utover.startnr, utover.navn, ovelse.navn
    FROM utover, ovelse
    WHERE ovelse.navn in (
     SELECT DISTINCT ovelse.navn
     FROM utover, deltakelse, ovelse
     WHERE utover.navn = 'Carl Lewis'
     AND deltakelse.utover = utover.startnr
     AND deltakelse.ovelse = ovelse.navn
     GROUP BY ovelse.navn, utover.startnr

     INTERSECT

     SELECT DISTINCT ovelse.navn
     FROM utover, deltakelse, ovelse
     WHERE utover.navn <> 'Carl Lewis'
     AND deltakelse.ovelse = ovelse.navn
     AND deltakelse.utover = utover.startnr
  GROUP BY ovelse.navn, utover.startnr
 );

Comment: please add your answer in Answers section, it would be helpful for everybody.

Comment: I can't answer my own question because my reputation is under 10

Answer (score 0):

`INTERSECT` returns any values that exist in both queries, but your first query selects `utover.startnr` which never occurs in the second query, so your result set will always be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps rewording the joins will help you see the problem.

```
SELECT utover.startnr, utover.navn
FROM utover
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM
            (ovelse AS ovelse2 INNER JOIN deltakelse AS deltakelse2 ON
                deltakelse2.ovelse = ovelse2.navn
            ) INNER JOIN utover AS utover2 ON
                utover2.startnr = deltakelse2.utover
        WHERE
            ovelse2.navn = utover.navn AND
            utover2.navn = 'Carl Lewis'
    ) AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM
            (ovelse AS ovelse3 INNER JOIN deltakelse AS deltakelse3 ON
                deltakelse3.ovelse = ovelse3.navn
            ) INNER JOIN utover AS utover3 ON
                utover3.startnr = deltakelse3.utover
        WHERE
            ovelse3.navn = utover.navn AND
            utover3.navn <> 'Carl Lewis'
    )
```